# how to set an enum instance by iterating through an enum

Tags: c#, enums

Not sure how to express by word what I want. I need to set an enum type given an input. Example code follows:

```
    Class Foo{
        enum Color{
           BLUE,
           RED,
           YELLOW
        }
        public Color color;

        public setColor(string col){
            var colorsEnum = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Color));
            foreach(var c in colorsEnum){
                if(c == col)
                    color = c.getEnum();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean [Enum.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to even loop through the names, why not just use `Contains`?

The trick here is to use `Enum.Parse`. Just stick a call to `Enum.Parse` after you checked that the color is valid:

```
public void setColor(string col){
    if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(Color)).Contains(col)) {
        color = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), col);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enum.TryParse<Color>(string value, bool ingnoreCase, out Color result)` to convert the string to an enum value.

```
Color color;
if (!Enum.TryParse<Color>("blUE", true, out color))
{
    color = Color.YELLOW; // default value
}
```

Try the fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/7S6IFf

Comment: That would be great, but wouldn't work in my case.
I didn't say in the question, but I really need to iterate through all the enums and check if my input string contains the color. Because the input can be "banana yellow".